# Server not able to send DB Mail

Tags: windows, email, server

I have a windows based application which triggers an email as soon as it finds any error in the process. There is a trigger defined on the database table which checks the database entry and if it finds any error it executes sp_send_dbmail from MSDB. The application is hosted on windows server and users are using this application with the help of CITRIX. So my problem is when application is used from CITRIX it is able to send an email for any error but when its directly used from server it does not triggers any mail for error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try sending a test email and then view the error message as indicated on step 9 in the "Sending Test E-mail" link below.

**Troubleshooting Database Mail: Sending Test E-Mail**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190413(v=sql.105).aspx

The following troubleshooting link includes details about the proper user configuration required:

**Troubleshooting Database Mail: General steps**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187540(v=sql.105).aspx